# socat:get sender's IP address

Tags: tcp, ip, socat

I use following code to receive a connection:

`socat TCP-LISTEN:4000,fork EXEC:"./myscrpit"`

I need to have a sender's IP address in my script but `SOCAT_PEERADDR` is not set, what is the problem?

Comment: Show us the script (at least the portion that prints `SOCAT_PEERADDR`).

Comment: for solving this problem my script just print `SOCAT_PEERADDR`:
`echo $SOCAT_PEERADDR`

Comment: Well it works for me so there must be something off. Are you sure that line is reached ? Which version are you using (I'm using `1.7.1.3-3`).

Comment: I `export` all of environment variable but none of `socat's` environment variable exist!!! (I'm using same version as you)

Comment: Are you positively sure you're printing it right ? :-)

Comment: None of environment variables set, Should I make something on??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `pktinfo` option for `TCP-LISTEN` so use following code:

`socat TCP-LISTEN:4000,pktinfo,fork EXEC:"./myscrpit`

Comment: how about `UDP`

Answer (score 1):

Just for information, but not an answer. This command works for me:

```
socat tcp-listen:12345 exec:./script
```

But this command does not:

```
socat exec:./script tcp-listen:12345
```

Hope this information helps. To me, if an address pair does not work, exchanging the order of the pair might work.

Comment: well yeah, if your ./script does not spit anything out to STDOUT then there's no communication

Answer (score 1):

**This seems to be the problem**: SOCAT_PEERADDR is an environment variable to access which you need to spawn a *shell*. As the socat-manpage (obtained with `man socat`) implies, the address type `SYSTEM:` should be used for this instead of `EXEC:`.

**Demo**: The following performed as desired for `socat` v1.7.3.3.

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:4000,fork SYSTEM:'echo "${SOCAT_PEERADDR}"'
```

To check, from another terminal, run

```
nc localhost 4000
```

This should show you your IP.